Unable to get an access token from a blazor web app
I am creating a blazor web app is using microsoft examples for authentication.
Authentication works great, both with a username/password and with 3rd party (google) auth. I also have a maui native app that uses the web login flow (using WebAuthenticator) and I need to pass back an access token so that the maui app can use the Web API's. The login flow works successfully.
Here is the component in /account that is called after a user successfully logs in. This components responsibility is to retrieve the token and send it back to the mobile app. However .GetTokenValue("access_token") is always null, despite the user being successfully logged in.
public partial class ReturnToMobileApp : ComponentBase
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    public HttpContext? HttpContext { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var auth = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
        var claims = auth.Principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault()?.Claims;
        var email = string.Empty;
        email = claims?.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;

        // Get parameters to send back to the callback
        var qs = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "access_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("access_token") },
                { "refresh_token", auth.Properties.GetTokenValue("refresh_token") ?? string.Empty },
                { "expires_in", (auth.Properties.ExpiresUtc?.ToUnixTimeSeconds() ?? -1).ToString() },
                { "email", email }
            };

        // Build the result url
        var url = "myapp://#" + string.Join(
            "&",
            qs.Where(kvp => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) && kvp.Value != "-1")
            .Select(kvp => $"{WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Key)}={WebUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value)}"));

        // Redirect to final url
        HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
    }
}



I have considered maybe something is wrong with my app startup configuration that's causing it not to store tokens, but any changes here have not affected the attempt to retrieve the access token from HttpContext.
services.AddAuthorizationCore();
services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>()
    .AddSignInManager()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddApiEndpoints();
services.AddScoped<IdentityUserAccessor>();
services.AddScoped<IdentityRedirectManager>();
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, IdentityRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider>();

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    // Password settings.
    options.Password = new PasswordOptions
    {
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequireNonAlphanumeric = true,
        RequireUppercase = true,
        RequiredLength = 8,
        RequiredUniqueChars = 1,
    };

    // Lockout settings.
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    // User settings.
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
});

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    // Cookie settings
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyApp.Cookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

Here is my login code, the user is successfully logged in and then redirected to the ReturnToMobileApp component to attempt to get the bearer token (I also tried to get the token here before the redirect, to no avail)
[Inject]
public required SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager { get; set; }

.... 

var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    Logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
    RedirectManager.RedirectTo("Account/ReturnToMobileApp");

I can also use postman to access the /login identity endpoint and it succeeds with a 200 OK, but does not return an access token. Examples I've seen show this endpoint should return a token.

UPDATE: I am now able to get a token via postman. It still does not work from within the components. I believe the following lines of code allowed the bearer token to be returned via postman:
.AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme, o =>
{
    o.BearerTokenExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
});



Can you show the code for your signin? This will help because at this point your trying to get what's in the cookie

@ZiregbeOtee done

Normally SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync creates a cookie with the identity of the user. Since this works for you for the web app and your endpoints are also here and you want to use JWT for your mobile app, you can add another authentication scheme(Bearer)
Create an endpoint for the mobile app to use for login. Use PasswordValidator to validate the user. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.passwordvalidator-1.validateasync?view=aspnetcore-8.0
On successful validation, create your JWT and return it.

I want the mobile app to have access to all login functionality that currently only exists on the web, such as registering a new account, changing passwords, login in, and lots of other features, seen in microsoft blazor hybrid samples. These components can't be used directly by the mobile app though so I'm using WebAuthenticator to access them in a web view in the mobile app. I do have a work around working by using the Identity /login API after a successful login I am able to retrieve a token to pass back to the mobile app. Not ideal as I'm authenticating twice, but it works.

Ok authenticating twice is good. When using the component on your mobile app the cookie will work. If you wish to call an endpoint directly use the token
